# save a image view in android studio

Tags: android

My app has an image view and a button, when i touch the button, the image view set invisible for example or change in another . The problem is when i close the app and open again the original state of the image view come back , i want to save the new state of the image ​​view but i dont no how, I need to use shared preferences or exist another way? Thank

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ImageView iv1;
    Button b1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        iv1=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv1);
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void a(View view){
        iv1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very simple to do with `SharedPreferences`:

```
private static final String KEY_VISIBILITY = "image_visibility";

private Button mButton;
private ImageView mImageView;

private SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
    mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.iv1);

    mImageView.setVisibility((mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(KEY_VISIBILITY, true)
            ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
}

public void onImageViewClick(View view) {
    boolean visibile = mImageView.getVisibility == View.VISIBLE;
    mImageView.setVisibility(visible ? View.INVISIBLE : View.VISIBLE);

    mSharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(KEY_VISIBILITY, !visible).apply();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you close the app or it is forced to close by OS when receives memory warning, all instance variables are lost and the app restarts when is reopened.

In order to do what you want, you need to keep ImageView status in a consistent storage. SharedPreferences are perfect for these situations, save the value everytime the button is clicked (you can save a boolean for visible/invisible status or the image reference string [url, local file path..]) Then, in the onCreate after findViewById you should retrieve saved status from preferences and render your ImageView as needed.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer use any kind of persistence to store your state. If you want to keep state even the application is killed or force closed then Preference, or try this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss");
            frameLayout_forBitmap.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            frameLayout_forBitmap.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap cache = frameLayout_forBitmap.getDrawingCache();
            try {
                FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(GlobalConfig.FilePath+"/Pic_"+ simpleDateFormat.format(new Date())+".jpg");
                cache.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream);
                fileOutputStream.flush();
                fileOutputStream.close();
                Toast.makeText(this, "Image Save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            } finally {
                frameLayout_forBitmap.destroyDrawingCache();
            }
```